# Inssert Statment, Values not Coded correctly

Tags: mysql, vba

Complete VBA newb...trying to enter some simple data into a simple table from an access form.

I used a youtube video and attempted to modify the code for my use, however I can get seem to get passed errors.

Here is the code mapped to the button that I am using to enter in the data

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

'add  data to table

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO EmpLunchTBL (FullName, ManName, TuesOrder, ThursOrder, PayType)" & _
    "VALUES (" ' & Me.txtName & ",'" & Me.txtMS & "','" & Me.cboTues & "','" & Me.cboThurs & "','" & Me.cboPaytype & "')"



End Sub
```

Pretty Straight forward, I know the issue lies somewhere within my values area...but again  total newb...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `"VALUES (" '` is the problem.  Try this:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

'add  data to table

Debug.Print "INSERT INTO EmpLunchTBL (FullName, ManName, TuesOrder, ThursOrder, PayType)" & _
"VALUES ('" & Me.txtName & "','" & Me.txtMS & "','" & Me.cboTues & "','" & Me.cboThurs & "','" & Me.cboPaytype & "')"



End Sub
```

Edit: Another single quote was missing.